# Iterate in a watch for a SQL Parameter List

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

So for example. I have an SP which passes 10 parameters, which then throws back a truncate error when attempting to run, I'd like to debug in SQL Studio so I add a watch on the parameter list which returns (when I expand at the first level) a list of all the names of the items in the parameter list.

E.g.

```
 1.  @User_ID
 2.  @FirstName

 ....
 10. @Date_Updated
```

Now I would like to be able in the watch window iterate through these and show the .Value of each of these parameters without having to specifiy 10 watches each being:

```
myParameterList(0).Value
myParameterList(1).Value
...
myParameterList(9).Value
```

Is there a way to iterate through a list in the watch window on visual studio to help with debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be not possible ([see](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/425e8f85-1eb5-4b7e-95b4-85fb31ef118b/is-it-possible-to-create-evaluation-loops-in-the-immediate-window)), but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980252/visualising-lists-in-debug-or-printing-to-immediate-windows) could be the solution.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. Couldn't quite figure out out the google-fu to find that first link.

Comment: Bounty in 22 hours once I can give it you.